# How to run pkg installer asking for password in GUI rather than in shell

Tags: macos, applescript, command-line, install, pkg

I tried to use `osascript` but no luck:

```
> osascript -e 'do shell script "installer -pkg /Users/syabro/Downloads/Crystal_Software.pkg -target /" with administrator privileges'

0:117: execution error: installer: Error - the package path specified was invalid: '/Users/syabro/Downloads/Crystal_Software.pkg'. (1)
```

However, this works:

```
> sudo installer -pkg /Users/syabro/Downloads/Crystal_Software.pkg -target /
installer: Package name is Crystal
installer: Upgrading at base path /
installer: The upgrade was successful.
```

I don't need installer GUI, I want it to be installed silently.

How to run pkg installer so that it prompts for a command-line password  rather than in a GUI dialog/prompt?

Comment: @bmike think your edit changed the meaning of the question. They want to run the installer silently (without GUI) with just a GUI prompt for the admin password. Not sure why a Terminal prompt doesn’t match the use case though.

Comment: May need to revert my edit or have the OP clarify. I thought I knew exactly what they meant but then saw the deleted answer and comments.